# Does my asymmetric/symmetric mixed file encryption pseudo code pass sanity check?

Tags: aes, file-encryption, aes-gcm

I realize this depends on my implementation and the implementation of the libraries I use. I am asking about my process assuming that the encryption libraries and my code are not flawed/compromised, the user's password is secure and the machine is not compromised.

The goal here is to protect the confidentiality of the files with a password, and be able to encrypt them without entering a password.

```
Initial setup:
- Generate an RSA keypair
- Prompt user for password and assume they use a sufficiently secure one
- Encrypt private key in DER format, pkcs=8, scheme = scryptAndAES256-CBC with the user password

For each file:
- Generate a random session key of 32 bytes
- Encrypt session key with initial public key
- Generate a random nonce of 12 bytes
- Write to output file:
  - Encrypted session key
  - Nonce
  - Encrypted file stream with AES GCM using random 32B session key and 12B nonce

When decrypting a file
- Prompt user for their password, decrypt initial private key
- Read the encrypted session key and nonce from the beginning of the file
- Decrypt the session key with the initial private key
- Decrypt the file stream with the session key and nonce
```

The only other things to note are that I chose GCM for its speed, over CBC for instance. I also am aware of the collision issue with using a random nonce, however I understand that this would be an issue more if I had billions of files using the same session key. And with a 32 byte random key I basically have 44 bytes of space to avoid collision. It is desirable for me to not have to keep track of a nonce.

Are there any issues with this plan or would this be a secure way to protect the privacy of files assuming the pseudo code was properly implemented?

Comment: The scheme is typical and I can't see apparent flaw so far. But if it were me, I won't let the task of proving security rob my sleep and hair - I'd use existing established file encryption product such as 7-zip (or RAR if you can spare some bucks), though they don't have public-key encryption.

Comment: PGP and GnuGPG are also good, they have GUI derivatives I believe.

Comment: "Encrypt session key with initial public key" and "decrypt initial private key" are severely under-specified; ton of mistakes can be made there, like using $x\mapsto x^e\bmod n$ for encryption of the session key, or using [RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=23). To a lesser degree, "Generate an RSA keypair" and parameterization of  scrypt also are under-specified even if we only consider security.

Comment: Also beware that repeating a known key + IV combination for structured data such as an RSA key is dangerous practice and may leak information about the wrapped key (**PS Hi HSM vendors, are you listening?**)